# Irish National Grid shapefile

Tags: data

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

Does anybody know where I can obtain a shapefile or similar for the Irish National Grid? I need a 1 km vector grid with the associated grid references given within an attribute field.

Comment: 1. You want a shapefile of 1km square polygons? 2. Do you know the EPSG code for the Irish NG? EPSG:29902? http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/29902/

Comment: Or 29903? Or 2157 (Irish Transverse Mercator)?

Comment: ING has a set of [grid square references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_grid_reference_system) somewhat like MGRS/USNG in the US. British National Grid has similar.

Comment: It looks like EPSG 29902 is the most recent. I'm surprised how difficult it is to find an Irish grid vector. For example, the OSGB grid is available from https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids. I believe it's also available through Ordnance Survey or Natural England, but Charles' GitHub repository is the most easily accessible source.